# How to get input from keyboard while doing other things at the same time?

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm using C (gcc) and ncurses, to make a program that will be monitoring data coming from the serial port. The program has a big `while`, where it reads the data coming from the port and at the same time, it prints that info in the screen...

But the problem is here:

How can it read input from my keyboard, (since `getch()` freezes the program until it gets an input) and at the same time read info coming from the port?

Maybe I have to use another way (not the big `while`), so ideas are welcome!

Comment: You might want to investigate threads: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computer_science)

Comment: or `select()`, for that matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

make **getch** a non-blocking call using **nodelay** option.

```
nodelay(stdscr,TRUE);
```

More info can be found at http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?topic=nodelay

Comment: That link doesn't actually mention `nodelay()`

Comment: Its not related to answer, hence its added as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment you maybe have the function kbhit(), it just peaks in the keyboard buffer and returns non zero if there is a key there - then you can do getch().

(conio.h)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe fork()?  Just keep in mind that the child runs in a separate process so variables can't be directly shared between them

```
pid_t pID = fork();
if (pID == 0) {                // child
   // Code  executed only by child process
   // getch() ...
} else if (pID < 0) {          // failed to fork
   // Throw exception
   // ... 
} else {                       // parent
   // Code executed only by parent process
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know this can cause headaches - caveat emptor.

Comment: That's an elegant way... I didn't know that. But when working with ncurses, I think that the nodelay option is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`select()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or [`poll()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll).  They both do the same thing, but with different interfaces.  You give it a list of file descriptors, and it will wait until at least one of those descriptors is ready, then return and tell you which ones can be read from (or written to) without blocking.  Check out the links for examples and more details.

Answer (score -1):

use  `cbreak()` to disable line buffering

```
nodelay(win, TRUE);
```

this will get you a non blocking `getch()` function.

Comment: This will still block until a key is pressed.